# Feature Description tutorial not working opencv

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, crash

I tried the tutorial about feature description on opencv.com and the program crashes with the error:

```
Debug assertion failed , Expression: vector iterator outside range
```

in the line_

```
detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
```

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.11, with Visual Studio 2010, and I'm linking to `opencv_<module>2411d.lib` libraries in library directory `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib`

The code is here :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\legacy\legacy.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Mat img_1 = imread("3.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img_2 = imread("2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if (!img_1.data || !img_2.data)
    {
        cout << " Nu au fost afisate imaginile" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int minHessian = 400;
    imshow("1.png", img_1);
    imshow("2.png", img_2);


    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

    detector.detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
    detector.detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

    extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
    extractor.compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors with a brute force matcher
    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
    vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

    //-- Draw matches
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2, matches, img_matches);

    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow("Matches", img_matches);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is when it starts to crash:

[image]

Comment: I bet you have opencv 3.0, while this tutorial is from opencv 2.4.X

Comment: post also the error message. (You should also update to a recent version.)

Comment: the error " Debug assertion failed , Expresion: vector iterator outside range" . If you look on the image above you see where it crashes. And my mistake i have opencv 2.4.11

Comment: Post also your library directories

Comment: C:\opencv\build\include - at Executable directories ; C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib - at Include directories; opencv_core2411d.lib
opencv_imgproc2411d.lib
opencv_highgui2411d.lib
opencv_features2d2411.lib
opencv_calib3d2411.lib , opencv_nonfree2411d.lib at linker

Comment: _library_, not _include_ path

Comment: include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>

#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>

#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp>

#include <opencv2\legacy\legacy.hpp>

Comment: everything seems ok. I can run the code with no errors, and you seem to link correctly against libraries for VS2010 in debug mode.

Comment: So you have no crash ? What version of opencv do you have ?

Comment: I'm using 2.4.9 for this test, but there's no difference from 2.4.11

Comment: Did you copied dll into the folder that contains the .exe? Or you added the bin folder to PATH?

Comment: So for you the program works and it shows you the images corectly with the keypoints detected and matched ?

Comment: which dll ? opencv_nonfree.dll ?

Comment: every opencv_<module>d.dll

Comment: how should i add the bin folder to the path ? sorry if it is a stupid question, i tried everything and in my mind is a mess now

Comment: simplest thing first... copy all opencv_<module>d.dll that you find in C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin folder into the same path of the.exe (should be <some_folder>\test1\Debug)

Comment: Did it, still crashes

Comment: that's wierd :D. Do you have other OpenCV versions installed?

Comment: No, only this version, i know its weird :)), i cannot posibly understand why it not works. Can you upload the images you put in the program, maybe i am loading bad images

Comment: well, images are loaded correctly or you would have `cout << " Nu au fost afisate imaginile" << endl;`. Try with the images from the opencv samples just to be sure. Should be something like C:\opencv\sources\samples\c\ box_png and box_in_scene.png

Comment: Those are my images. Stil the crash . I will install again opencv, i don't know what to do anymore... It still weird , because i did a corner Harris problem and it works, shi-thomas and it works, and other problems from the tutorials on the website. Only the Feature Matcing with FLANN, and SURF dont

Comment: There is no problem with the code, since it runs ok for me. Probably you messed up something in setup. The only (visible) difference s that I'm using VS2013. Sorry but I have no other clues to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help !